# Adding X axis title causes Uncaught RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to add a title to the X axis to a Chart.js chart, but when I put the title attribute on the x axis, I get an error Uncaught RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range, but it doesn't happen if I add a title to the Y axis.

The problem only happens when I add the title attribute, if I take it out, the chart works perfectly.

```
grafica_roi = new Chart($('#grafica_roi'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'],
        datasets: [{
            //label: 'Beneficio obtenido',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            backgroundColor: '#F0A202'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size:function(context) {
                            var width = context.chart.width;
                            
                            if(width<=320) {
                                size = 12;
                            }
                            else {
                                if(width>320 && width<600) {
                                    size = 16;
                                }
                                else {
                                    size = 20;
                                }
                            }
                            //var size = Math.round(width / 32);

                            return size;
                        },
                        weight: "bold"
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    display: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Ahorro',
                    display: true
                }
            },
            x: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size:function(context) {
                            var width = context.chart.width;
                            
                            if(width<=320) {
                                size = 12;
                            }
                            else {
                                if(width>320 && width<600) {
                                    size = 16;
                                }
                                else {
                                    size = 20;
                                }
                            }
                            //var size = Math.round(width / 32);

                            return size;
                        },
                        weight: "bold"
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    display: false
                },
                //this title attribute below causes the problem
                title: {
                    text: 'Años',
                    display: true
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            autocolors: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Retorno de inversión",
                font: {
                    size: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The data is added dynamically, but the chart shows the problem as soon as the page is loaded, so it's not about the data.

[image: error chart js]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found the problem. The problem was I was using v3.1 Chart.js, while trying to use settings from v3.5 Chart.js.

Changed the JS file version and now it's working well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! I had exactly the same issue.