# chart js error in next js site hosted on netlify

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, netlify

everthing is working fine in development on my local machine,
but when I deploy my site to netlify, I get this wierd error in console.

[image]

the page data is gotten using getStaticProps function and then passed to the page as props.

here is how the data looks like

```
[
  [ 17671, 19856, 37527 ],  [ 4887, 5418, 10305 ],
  [ 2803, 2303, 5106 ],     [ 8617, 9403, 18020 ],
  [ 12664, 15722, 28386 ],  [ 4227, 3359, 7586 ],
  [ 1371, 1545, 2916 ],     [ 17526, 14297, 31823 ],
  [ 6883, 4781, 11664 ],    [ 9805, 10000, 19805 ],
  [ 11068, 12888, 23956 ],  [ 4570, 4722, 9292 ],
  [ 15428, 17309, 32737 ],  [ 3565, 3656, 7221 ],
  [ 8750, 10443, 19193 ],   [ 1771, 1432, 3203 ],
  [ 8495, 9979, 18474 ],    [ 288, 265, 553 ],
  [ 21130, 19321, 40451 ],  [ 6867, 6556, 13423 ],
  [ 2656, 2092, 4748 ],     [ 967, 656, 1623 ],
  [ 4540, 4505, 9045 ],     [ 7025, 7108, 14133 ],
  [ 53134, 59829, 112963 ], [ 8640, 9028, 17668 ],
  [ 6759, 7119, 13878 ],    [ 28803, 31362, 60165 ],
  [ 7346, 7630, 14976 ],    [ 9771, 10963, 20734 ],
  [ 15783, 17397, 33180 ],  [ 9847, 9706, 19553 ],
  [ 15154, 17577, 32731 ],  [ 1056, 874, 1930 ],
  [ 3260, 2476, 5736 ],     [ 1488, 1424, 2912 ],
  [ 1656, 1154, 2810 ]
]
```

it is an array of arrays of 3 numbers.
please how do I solve this?

Comment: Does on of these answers solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887123 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/71532100

Comment: Or if none of the above do, does this answer your question: [Error "RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range" with ChartJS in Next.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840076/error-rangeerror-minimumfractiondigits-value-is-out-of-range-with-chartjs-in)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `swcMinify: false` false in your `next.confug.js`. This is currently a bug in the swcMinifier and you will need to wait until they have fixed it before you can enable it again.